# Get the shipping and billing address of a customer in SuiteScript

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to get the default shipping and billing addresses for a customer in SuiteScript.

```
    var shipaddress = null;
    var billaddress = null;

    //Find the default billing and shipping addresses
    var add_Count = customerRec.getLineCount('addressbook');
    for (var i = 1; i <= add_Count; i++){
        customerRec.selectLine('addressbook', i);
        var def_Bill = customerRec.getCurrentSublistValue('addressbook', 'defaultbilling');
        var def_Ship = customerRec.getCurrentSublistValue('addressbook', 'defaultshipping');
        if(def_Bill){
            billaddress = customerRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
        } else if(def_Ship){
            shipaddress = customerRec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
        }
    }
```

With this code I am able to get the first one, but as soon as it hits

```
customerRec.selectLine('addressbook', i);
```

for the second time it throws the error.

```
SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION
You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer. Please see below.

```
var add_Count = customerRec.getLineCount('addressbook');
for (var i = 0; i < add_Count; i++){
    var def_Bill = customerRec.getSublistValue('addressbook', 'defaultbilling', i);
    var def_Ship = customerRec.getSublistValue('addressbook', 'defaultshipping', i);
    var anAddress = customerRec.getSublistSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress', i);
    if(def_Bill){
        billaddress = anAddress;
    } else if(def_Ship){
        shipaddress = anAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out again. I stumbled across this a few years later ;)

Comment: Did you just thank yourself?